# Duplicate content with incremental titles. How is this happening?

Tags: content

I was looking through the crawl results of my SEO Moz app and saw that there are somehow many copies of certain pages that have titles that are the exact same except for a number added to them. An example is in the image. How could this be happening?[image]

Comment: You probably should make your question better to understand. For me this reads like you have a lot in mind, but I just don't get it cauz I don't have. Do you want to get rid of those? Do you have any guess what the number at the end is for? Can you post your permalinks configuration? Are that pages or posts? Do you want duplicates or not? ... ? ... ? ... Please add some more context. I mean having an image does already helps, but I still have problems to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are attachment URLs. They are created for all images in your post. You have a gallery with 17 images, so for each image an URL with the structure `[post_url]/[attachment_name]` is created. [`/2010/07/2011-honda-odyssey-official-details-photos-and-specs/`](http://paragonhondainfo.com/2010/07/2011-honda-odyssey-official-details-photos-and-specs/) is the post URL, `2011_hondy_odyssey-2` is the name of one of the images in it (created based on the file name when you upload it). You can style these pages by modifying the `attachment.php` template file.